# how do you subset the based on the count rows per each unique entry

Tags: r

I have a data df like this:

```
 Hostname                Date                 CPU       
 Server01  2015-11-02 00:00:53                54 
 Server01  2015-11-02 00:15:53                54
 Server01  2015-11-02 00:30:53                54 
 Server02  2015-11-02 00:45:53                54 
 Server02  2015-11-02 01:00:53                54
```

Under Hostname, there are bunch of different servers. I need to make sure that number of lines for each servers greater than 2 and get a final df.

Is there an easy way to subset the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Hostname) %>% filter(n() > 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `base R`:

```
x = df$Hostname
df[is.element(x, names(table(x))[table(x)>2]),]
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Hostname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Server01", 
"Server02"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(1:5, .Label = c("2015-11-02 00:00:53", 
"2015-11-02 00:15:53", "2015-11-02 00:30:53", "2015-11-02 00:45:53", 
"2015-11-02 01:00:53"), class = "factor"), CPU = c(54L, 54L, 
54L, 54L, 54L)), .Names = c("Hostname", "Date", "CPU"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: when I do your suggestions, I still get the same number of rows as original.

Comment: Works fine on my machine too. Unless we're misinterpreting the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use data.table (to make the ansers complete in base-R, dplyr and data.table:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[,N:=.N,by=Hostname][N>2,]
```

I use N:=.N and not .N because otherwise data get aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

another variant with `base R`:

```
df[ave(df$CPU, df$Hostname, FUN=length)>2,]
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Hostname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Server01", 
"Server02"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(1:5, .Label = c("2015-11-02 00:00:53", 
"2015-11-02 00:15:53", "2015-11-02 00:30:53", "2015-11-02 00:45:53", 
"2015-11-02 01:00:53"), class = "factor"), CPU = c(54L, 54L, 
54L, 54L, 54L)), .Names = c("Hostname", "Date", "CPU"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```